# UINavigationController custom transition removes view underneath

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uikit

I'm implementing my own UINavigationController transition using:

```
- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
                              animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation
                                           fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC
                                             toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC{
    return self;
}
```

What happens though, the pushing viewController.view disappears as soon as the transition finishes. I present views using

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:pushedViewController animated:YES];
```

Is there a way to tell TransitionCoordinator not to delete the presenting controller's view when I push them using UINavigationController? Do I really need to implement my own ContainerView with all the logic?

Comment: Yes, without a containerviewcontroller there is always only one viewcontroller active.

Comment: Isn't there a way to make the transition: modal like when presenting modal view controller to view controller?

Comment: so you want to add navigationcontroller with custom animation transition?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that, but after the transition finishes, the view underneath disappears.

Comment: You must use a ContainerViewController or just use one viewController with multiple views and show only the views needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finished up making my own ContainerViewController. Now I have total control over views' lifespan.